# Javascript put custom request in cache

Tags: javascript, caching, jsonp, service-worker

I want to cache the result of a jsonp query in my service worker. Therefore,  I wrap the data in a Response object and try to "put" it in the cache:

```
data = {foo:1, bar:2};
caches.open("my_cache")
.then(function (cache) {
    let response = new Response(JSON.stringify(data));
    cache.put("test.json", response)
        .then(data => console.log("sucess", data))
        .catch(err => console.log("failure", err));
})
.catch(err => console.log("Something went wrong", err));
```

unfortunately I get an exception. The output is

```
failure DOMException
```

which is not very specific. Is there any possibility to store custom data in a cache? It seems that cache.put raises this exception.

Comment: There should not be this sort of limitation. Your code does not have any error handling – meaning it's missing a catch after the then. You should add error handling and inspect what exactly is going wrong. Looking at the error message it's not even clear if it comes from the code you copy-pasted :)

Comment: I have added some error handling now. cache.put raises this exception. I can execute this code in a browser javascript console to get this error.

Comment: That's interesting. When I execute the code in the console (Chrome 76), I don't get any errors, only the success msg. I can also confirm that the response was saved in the cache correctly.

Comment: I now tried it on a different computer and there it works. So it seems that it was a problem with the computer. Maybe because I have to view space on my hard drive (< 1GB). Thank you for your help.